# Relocating the repository

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I have VisualSVN Server installed on my machine (which acts as a Subversion server). I have several projects in here, and now I am going to format this machine, and reinstall VisualSVN Server on it.

How can I access my old repository with all the old projects I have there?
I just want to find a way how to not affect any of the old projects that are in the SVN.

Can someone help me out and tell me which files should I backup and how to do the transition properly?

Note: I'm using TortoiseSVN client.

Comment: TortoiseSVN as SVN **client** is irrelevant to administrative server-side task

Answer (score 0):

1. Easy way - save tree from SVNParentPath of server, return back after reinstall (as repos and content will appaar automagically)
2. SVN-style way - [`svnadmin dump`](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnadmin/c/dump/) every repo, [`svnadmin load`](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnadmin/c/load/) dump later (create repository in server's applet before load).